# javascript code does not show me expected output

Tags: javascript, notepad++

i am writing javascript code  on  nodepad++,i am at beginner level and write just this code

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date();
var time=d.getHours();
if(time<10)
{
document.write("<b> good morning </b>");

}
else
{
document.write ("<b> good afternoon </b>");

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

then from  editor nodepad++,i clicked run  in  google chrome,but got only this

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date();
var time=d.getHours();
if(time<10)
{
document.write("<b> good morning </b>");

}
else
{
document.write ("<b> good afternoon </b>");

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

copy of code and not result,why?

Comment: Did you save with the `htm` or `html` extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you saved your file as `txt` and not as `html`. Then the browser would only show you the content and do not render the code.

Save it as HTML File and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

save ur file as .html instead of .js and open in browser it is inline javascript !!!
it should work